# push_back() changes size of other vector in function

Tags: c++, vector, unique-ptr

I'm making a class which has a function that concatenates two vectors of unique_ptrs. When I use the push_back function, the size of the parameter vector changes, and I don't know why.

```
class A: public vector<unique_ptr<int>>{        
    public:
        A& concatenate(A& c);   
};

A& A::concatenate(A& c) {
    for(int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++) { //this loop never stops
        push_back(make_unique<int>()); //this line changes the size of c?
        (*this)[(*this).size() - 1] = move(c[i]);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

The for loop doesn't stop running because every time the push_back method is used, the size of c is also incremented by 1.

I also thought to use resize() before the for loop, and then move all the pointers, but I want to know why the push_back method changes another vector.

Comment: Your `concatenate` function does not return a value, even though it is declared to return an `A&`.  Thus the behavior is undefined.  Is this your real code?

Comment: That might happen when this A and the c A objects are same, i.e. you are trying to call concatenate on an object and passing the same object as param to concatenate

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Sorry, I forgot the add the return statement, it is in my code and the behavior is as described.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  We have no idea where `c` comes from.

Comment: @Nitesh Thank you, that is what is happening. The first call of this function tries to concatenate vector a with itself!

Comment: Why `push_back(make_unique<int>())` and then a move? Why don't you just use a move inserter instead of this odd code?

Comment: Remember that `std::vector` isn't really desinged to be publicly inherited. If you just want to inherit the public interface consider using `private` inheritance instead.

Comment: And if all you want to do is to add a "concatenate" function, why not just use [`insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) to add one vector to the end of the other?

Comment: @LorenzoDB Added comments as answer

Answer (score 0):

That might happen when this A and the c A objects are same, i.e. you are trying to call concatenate on an object and passing the same object as param to concatenate.
So actually push_back is not changing size of *another* vector. Its the same vector you are working on.

On a sidenote, there are few issues with your code and post

1. As @PaulMcKenzie said, you should post an MCVE
2. In general, its not a good idea to derive from STL containers
3. Unless you are trying to learn how to implement, you should first try to find and use methods provided by STL containers. e.g. insert as suggested by
   @Some programmer dude.